# Laravel 4.1 relative urls resolution

Tags: php, apache, laravel, proxy

I've found many references to the relative urls in laravel 4, but no solution to my (maybe easy) problem.
With a fresh installation of Laravel 4.1, I just try to load a style.css file, which I've put it in public/css/style.css

I'm calling it in view/hello.php with a simple

```
<link href="<?php echo URL::asset('css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If I open in broser from internal network, it works fine.
If I open from outside with a reverse proxy rule on the firewall, the css is not loaded cause it links to
192.168.1.1/css/style.css

I've done the same thing with Yii framework and it's working fine both from internal and external request, cause
I've seen I've relative path to css (/css/style.css).

My problem is that I've done an application with laravel that is working smoothly in intranet, but I've to put it
available outside with a reverse proxy rule (something like myapp.mydomain.com:1234).
Apart from css or js files to be loaded, the application doesn't work from outside cause all the routes are resolved
to the internal server ip (192.168.1.1).

Trying again to make a simple app with Yii, it works smoothly, both intranet than internet.

Now my question is: am I missing something in laravel configuration, I need to find a workaround or I need to rewrite
my app with a differenet framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually relative URLs doesn't need anything more than the relative file path in pure HTML:

```
echo '<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
```

No Laravel URL building involved.

Comment: You are right about css or js, but as I wrote, the whole application is not working cause I use the url generator everywhere to call the routes, like URL::route('module.controller.action')

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your external requests are not hitting the project root folder.

I think you'd need to set up a virtual host to direct traffic from `myapp.mydomain.com:1234` to `your.internal.address/public` folder of your Laravel project.